# Adding only one subnode using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

giving command

```
xml ed -N x=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee -s //x:web-app/x:security-constraint/x:auth-constraint -t elem -n role-name -v appuser WEB-INF/web.xml
```

But the above command is adding two sub nodes named `appuser` because of twice occurence of "web-app/security-constraint/auth-constraint"in my xml. I want to only add one . How can i do this?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: it is somewhat like this <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> <security-constraint><authorize-constraint><role-name>role1</role-name><role-name>role2</role-name></authorize-constraint></security-constraint><security-constraint><authorize-constraint><role-name>role1</role-name></authorize-constraint></security-constraint></web-app>

Comment: I want to add my value only at the first occurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your xpath only match the first security-constraint element:

```
//x:web-app/x:security-constraint[1]/x:auth-constraint
```